# MVC Area - How to Link to Root folder in BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to define a link to LogOff controller which is in my Root shared folder; within BeginForm tag.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", action = "Account/LogOff"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
   @: | <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>

}
}
else {
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") 
@: | 
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")
}
```

Above works fine if I'm in root folder. But if clicked from Areas, it gives me **The resource cannot be found** error.

**Requested URL: /MyApp/Area/Account/LogOff**

The correct link should be /MyApp/Account/LogOff

I saw examples using @HTML.ActionLink but would prefer to keep define it in BeginForm, so the URL is not revealed to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code.

First I mapped a route as follows

```
//Route config for logging off from areas.
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "LogOff",
   url: "Account/LogOff/",
   defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff" }
);
```

Then calling the route to logout, I used the following

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("LogOff", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to just add the Area routevalue to the BeginForm parameters. Leave it blank to point it to the root area, like this: ***new { Area = "" }***

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { Area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
}
```

This is using MVC 5